# Improving multivariate regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, multivariate-testing

I recently conducted a survey within an IT company concering user satisfaction with a specific data management solution. There was one question about the overall satisfaction (dependend variable for my regression). And then various questions about more specific aspects like data quality etc. (independend variables in my regression).

With the help of R, I created a multivariate regression in order to figure out which of the various aspects are most important for the customer satisfaction. However, I believe my results are not 100% correct since some of the results dont make sense. For instance, according to the standardized coeffizient increasing data quality results in less user satisfaction. From my point of view, the coefficient should be positive for all variables.

Maybe somebody here can help me/ give me some tips how to improve my model. Down below you can find my code and the results (anonymized). The rows labeled M-AV are my independend variables. In the columns to the right you can find the standardized coefficent, the standard error, t value and p-value.

```
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUbujtw5Azc

#Librarys laden
library(lmtest)
library(car)
library(sandwich)


#Daten einlesen
daten <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T, sep=";")

#Spalte K transformieren (wird als chr erkannt, ist aber numeric)
daten <- transform(daten, K = as.numeric(K))
str(daten)

#Regressions Modell
#modell <- lm(H ~ M + N + O + P + X + Y + Z + AA + AB + AE + AF + AG + AJ + AL + AM + AN + AQ + AR + AS + AU + AV, daten)
modell <- lm(C ~ M + N + O + P + X + Y + Z + AA + AB + AE + AF + AG + AJ + AL + AM + AN + AQ + AR + AS + AU + AV, daten)
#Vorraussetzungen

# 1 Normalverteilung der Residuen
#Plot Punkte sollten ca. auf Linie liegen (entspricht Normalverteilung). Abweichung am Anfang und Ende ist OK.
plot(modell, 2)

# 2a Homoskedastizität (Streuen Residuen gleich)
plot(modell, 1) #sollte ca. auf Ideallinie liegen

#Breusch-Pagan Test, Null-Hypothese: es liegt Homoskedastizität vor
#falls p-value > 0.05 wird Nullhypothese beibehalten
bptest(modell)

#3 Keine Multikollinarität (unabhängige Variablen korrelieren zu stark)
#Vif sollte auf jeden Fall unter 10 liegen, konservativer unter 6
vif(modell)

#4 Ausreißer/ Einflussreiche Fälle
#https://bjoernwalther.com/cook-distanz-in-r-ermitteln-und-interpretieren-ausreisser-erkennen/
plot(modell, 4)

#Robuste Standardfehler
coeftest(modell, vcov=vcovHC(modell, type ="HC3"))

#Auswertung
summary(modell)

#F-Statistik hat Nullhypothese, das Erklärungsmodell kein Erklärungsbeitrag leistet --> hier <.05, wird also verworfen!
#R2 Wert --> ca. 60% der Variable wird durch Variabeln erklärt (eigentlich 40%, siehe ajustiertes R2)

#standartisierte Koeffizienten um einflussreichste Variable zu finden
zmodell <- lm(scale(C) ~ scale(M)+ scale(N) + scale(O) + scale(P) + scale(X) + scale(Y) + scale(Z) + scale(AA) + scale(AB) + scale(AE) + scale(AF) + scale(AG) + scale(AJ) + scale(AL) + scale(AM) + scale(AN) + scale(AQ) + scale(AR) + scale(AS) + scale(AU) + scale(AV), data = daten)
summary(zmodell)
```

[image]

```
dput(head(j, 20))
structure(list(A = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L), B = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), C = c(10L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 
1L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 3L), D = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), E = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L), F = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L), G = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), H = c(6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L), I = c(6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), 
    J = c(3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), K = c(5, 3.67, 5.33, 4.33, 5, 
    3.33, 5, 3.67, 5.33, 4.67, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3.33, 5.67, 4, 4, 
    4.67, 2.67), L = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), M = c(4L, 2L, 6L, 
    6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 3L), N = c(6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L), O = c(5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
    6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    3L), P = c(6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L), Q = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), R = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), S = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), T = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), U = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), V = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), W = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), X = c(4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L), Y = c(5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L
    ), Z = c(5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L), AA = c(6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 2L
    ), AB = c(6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
    5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L), AC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), AD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AE = c(5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L
    ), AF = c(4L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L), AG = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L
    ), AH = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AI = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), AJ = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L), AK = c(NA, NA, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, NA, 6L, 5L, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA
    ), AL = c(4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L), AM = c(5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L
    ), AN = c(1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
    5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), AO = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), AP = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AQ = c(3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
    1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L
    ), AR = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
    6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L), AS = c(1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
    1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L
    ), AT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AU = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L
    ), AV = c(6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L), AW = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), AX = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AY = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), AZ = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), BB = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), BD = c(5.25, 2.25, 5, 4.75, 5.25, 6, 5.75, 3.25, 5.75, 
    5.25, 3, 5, 4.75, 3.5, 4.75, 5.25, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 2.25), 
    BE = c(5.2, 2.6, 3.4, 4, 3.8, 6, 5, 2.6, 5, 4, 1.8, 4.2, 
    4.4, 2.8, 4.8, 4, 4, 2.6, 4.6, 1.6), BF = c(4.333333333, 
    1, 5.666666667, 2.666666667, 5.333333333, 5, 4, 3.333333333, 
    5, 4.333333333, 2, 3.333333333, 4.666666667, 3.333333333, 
    4.666666667, 3, 3, 3.333333333, 5.333333333, 1.666666667), 
    BG = c(3.25, 2, 5.75, 3.5, 4.25, 4.25, 4.75, 2.25, 5.75, 
    4, 2.25, 4.25, 5.25, 2.25, 5, 4.25, 3.75, 2.5, 5, 1.5), BH = c(1.666666667, 
    2, 5.333333333, 3.333333333, 6, 1, 5, 2, 6, 5, 5.666666667, 
    4, 6, 2.666666667, 5, 4, 2.666666667, 2, 4.333333333, 2), 
    BI = c(5.5, 3, 4.5, 4, 6, 2.5, 5.5, 2.5, 6, 4.5, 4, 4, 4, 
    6, 4.5, 6, 4, 6, 3.5, 2.5)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(daten)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(daten, 20))`.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) than  here, but it's probably not answerable as is; we have no idea what your predictors are. You could browse [these answers on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+coefficient+%22wrong+sign%22) to get some idea of the *possible* problems ...

Comment: Hey! I added the output below the picture. The code was allready included. The excel table basically just gives a quick overview over all the results from the multivariate regression. Column C is the overall satisfaction, all other columns that are used as independend variables are different quality factors such as data quality, uptime of the system etc. The NA values are rows I had to anonymize, but they are not relevant to the regression.

Comment: Regression coeff. signs opposite to what business dictates are a sign that a set of input variables are highly _positively_ correlated among each other. Considering you write _"all other columns [...] are [...] quality factors"_, this is very likely the case in your data. In such context, the negative coeffs. you observe should be doing minor adjustments to the prediction coming out of stronger positive coeffs. of a positively correlated variable driving the target in the expected business direction.

Comment: You would probably see that the variables with coeff. signs opposite to what is expected by business understanding have a smaller standardized coefficient (in absolute value) than the correlated variables that have the "correct" sign.
I suggest you analyze the correlation among input variables with the `vif` function in the `car` package and remove variables with very large VIF, say > 10. (Note: VIF stands for Variance Inflation Factor and measures how much the variance of regression coefficients are inflated due to correlation among input variables.)

Comment: @mastropi mhh thanks for the information, but I think this should not be the case since according to my variance-inflation-factor calculation there are no strong correlations. I also created a second regression model which consists only of 8 independend variables instead of 22 (I used a top-down approach to eliminate all non significant variables). I still end up with three variables that have a "wrong" sign.

In my original regression model all VIF-values were < 5 and in the new one all VIF-values are < 2.

Comment: Ok. But in my experience, the "wrong" sign can still happen when there is a mild positive correlation between two variables. In fact, the less strong variable in predicting the target is the one that would get the "wrong" sign, as it is helping improve the prediction of the target, *given* the value predicted by the first stronger variable. You can visualize this situation by doing a simple 3D scatter plot by hand on a model like `y = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2` where x1 and x2 are positively correlated. My advice: the "wrong" sign is not wrong if you (and possibly your client!) understand this.